# IHP - Is there a way to set the static assets directory?

Tags: ihp

I believe by default the IHP static directory is a relative directory to `pwd/static`. Is there a way to set it to another, fixed directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible in IHP. The "static/" directory is hardcoded in multiple places.

Comment: Well, I mentioned a while back how we had a race condition which ended up setting the current directory to the wrong one which broke the static assets. Thought we had it fixed but it seemed to happen again yesterday where suddenly CSS wasn't being served. It's kind of strange because I don't think we're even changing the directory now, so maybe this happened due to another issue. I need to dig deeper into the logs to see what I can see but I wondered if this might be a stop-gap solution in the meantime.

Comment: Ok that makes sense